# Generating variants

Tags: expl3, function

Does the following command just add an additional name for the function ? Would the arguments be identical to the original function ?

```
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \feuds_newteorema_simple:nn { VV }
```

Comment: No it generates a new command `\feuds_newteorema_simple:VV` as shown in several  of your previous questions. The new command will use the value of the supplied variables not the arguments directly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `V` variant is passed the value of the variable in the argument, not the argument itself.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\int_set:Nn \l_tmpa_int {42}

\cs_new:Npn \test_fun:n #1 {
  \typeout{ARG ~IS ~\exp_not:n{#1}}
}

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \test_fun:n {V}

\test_fun:n {\l_tmpa_int}

\test_fun:V \l_tmpa_int

\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

produces terminal output

```
ARG IS \l_tmpa_int 
ARG IS 42
```

Comment: Obviously, 42 ;).

Comment: @cfr that or emacs

Comment: Is emacs something the Vogons used?

Comment: Right, because `n` passes the variable with no modification.

Comment: @cfr Yes, the alien race use it. Would you like to know what browser they use up there too ?

Comment: No need for braces when calling `\test_fun:V` ?

Comment: @Veak I'm not sure. Will I regret it if I say 'yes'? You don't want braces because `\test_fun:V` absorbs a single token i.e. a variable name. `{\l_tmpa_int}` is three tokens. `\l_tmpa_int` is one. That's part of what the `V` specifier means. (Not all of it, because the function expects a particular sort of token, but part of it, because it expects only one token of that sort.)

Comment: I only say this.  Beware what you wish for ! ;)

Comment: @Veak Like `N`, `V` is strictly a single token so no braces

Comment: as Joseph says, braces would be wrong @Veak